# CollectionView items does not update while setting x:DataType to ViewModel in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a `CollectionView` that has its `ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection` and it works fine. But when I add `x:DataType="viewmodels:MyPageViewModel"` in the XAML, it does not show any items, even those items that are initialized in the ViewModel's constructor are not shown in the `CollectionView`. It also does not show updated items.

**Here's my XAML Code (MyPage.xaml):**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:MyPageViewModel"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>

            <Button Text="Add More" Command="{Binding AddMoreItemsCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Here I have specified Binding in the C# Code Behind (MyPage.xaml.cs):**

```cs
BindingContext = new ViewModels.MyPageViewModel();
```

**Here's my ViewModel (MyPageViewModel.cs):**

```cs
public class MyPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get { return strings; } set { strings = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Strings)); } }
    ObservableCollection<string> strings;

    public MyPageViewModel()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
    }

    public ICommand AddMoreItemsCommand => new Command(() =>
    {
        Strings.Add("4");
        Strings.Add("5");
        Strings.Add("6");
    });

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Note that if I remove `x:DataType="viewmodels:MyPageViewModel"`, everything works fine.
Also if I edit something in `ColllectionView` while the app is running, it renders the items properly as expected through **XAML Hot Reload**. But it doesn't fulfil the need as it does not work if I rerun the Project again.

Is there a bug in Xamarin Forms, I am running the latest Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2515, I have also tried it in Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2478? Or am I missing something? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3598

Comment: if you make a change to a property of an item, that item needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to update the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `x:DataType="modelOfYourCollection"` in `<DataTemplate>` of the `CollectionView`.

If you are using any control that has a DataTemplate you must also setup the compiled binding on it. Here, we have a `CollectionView` that is data bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>`. We can bring in the `System` namespace just like we did for the `viewmodels:MyPageViewModel` because we are using collection of string type and String class resides in System namespace.

- Firstly, add namespace in root of the page:

```xml
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
```

- And then in your `DataTemplate` add:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="sys:String">
```

If we are using our own Custom Model, add model's namespace at the root of the page and then specify model class in `DataTemplate` of the `CollectionView`. **Note** that we have to use Model and not ViewModel in the `DataTemplate`.

Rest of the code is correct

**Final XAML Code will look like:**

```xml
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyProject.Models"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:MyPageViewModel"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyPage">
    ...

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="sys:String">
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

    <!-- For collection of your custom model -->

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MonkeyModel">
                <Label Text="{Binding MonkeyName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Why use Compiled Bindings?** *Compiled bindings are resolved more quickly than classic bindings. Hence, improves data binding performance in Xamarin.Forms applications.*

- [Refer this blog by James Montemagno for more details.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/compiled-bindings-xamarin-forms/)
- [Refer here for Xamarin.Forms Compiled Bindings Official Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?WT.mc_id=compiledbindings-xamarinblog-jamont)